# Finding arrays that contain a subset of another array without using @> with postgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, greenplum

I have a table with `1.5 MM` records. Each record has a `row number` and an `array` with between `1 and 1,000` elements in the array. I am trying to find all of the arrays that are a subset of the larger arrays.

When I use the code below, I get  **ERROR: statement requires more resources than resource queue allows (possibly because there are over a trillion possible combinations)**:

```
select
   a.array as dup
from
   table a
left join
    table  b
on
  b.array @> a.array 
  and a.row_number <> b.row_number
```

Is there a more efficient way to identify which arrays are subsets of the other arrays and mark them for removal other than using `@>`?

Comment: Have you tried creating a GIN index on your array column?

Comment: GIN indexes are not supported by our database - it is on a version of Greenplum.

Comment: In case you were wondering about the row_number as it relates to this type of database - that was manually assigned using arbitrary ordering, but will always be the same each time I pull data from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see how to do this efficiently in a single declarative SQL statement without appropriate support from an index.   I don't know how well this would work with a GIN index,  but using a GIN index would certainly avoid the need to compare every possible pair of rows.

The first thing I would do is to carefully investigate the types of indexes you do have at your disposal,  and try creating one as necessary.

If that doesn't work,  the first thing that comes to my mind, procedurally speaking,  would be to sort all the arrays,  then sort the rows into a graded lexicographic order on the arrays.   Then start with the shortest arrays,  and work upwards as follows:   e.g. for [1,4,9],  check all the arrays with length <= 3 that start with 1 if they are a subset,   then check all arrays with length <= 2 that start with 4,  and then check all the arrays of length <= 1 that start with 9,  removing any found subsets from consideration as you go so that you don't keep re-checking the same rows over and over again.

I'm sure you could tune this algorithm a bit,  especially depending on the particular nature of the data involved.  I wouldn't be surprised if there was a much better algorithm;  this is just the first thing that I thought of.   You may be able to work from this algorithm backwards to the SQL you want,  or you may have to dump the table for client-side processing,  or some hybrid thereof.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code suggests that you are only interested in finding arrays that are subsets of *any* other array in another row of the table.

However, your query with a `JOIN` returns all combinations, possibly multiplying results.

Try an `EXISTS` semi-join instead, returning qualifying rows only *once*:

```
SELECT a.array as dup
FROM   table a
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   table b
   WHERE  a.array <@ b.array
   AND    a.row_number <> b.row_number
   );
```

With this form, Postgres can stop iterating rows as soon as the first match is found. If this won't go through either, try *partitioning* your query. Add a clause like

```
AND table_id BETWEEN 0 AND 10000
```

and iterate through the table. Should be valid for this case.

Aside: it's a pity that your derivate (Greenplum) doesn't seem to support GIN indexes, which would make this operation much faster. (The index itself would be big, though)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately using the table_id only worked if I set it to AND table_id BETWEEN 0 AND 500, meaning a lot of iteration. By using LIMIT 100000 and the end of my statement I was able to convince the system to run my code, however, which means far fewer iterations.